# Word 2013 export to PDF how to keep font vectorized

Tags: pdf, fonts, embedded, microsoft-word-2013

I have to use Myriad font with Word 2013 (I cannot use other font or software).

When export my Word doc to PDF, Myriad font is *bitmapped* (many pixels).

My question is : how to keep the font *vectorized* (without pixel)?

I've tried to go to the option -> save -> font embded but it's not working...

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is indeed a problem. and it still exists in Office 2016. There is a documented feature (aka bug) that Office doesn't know (or want) how to embed Open Type fonts, unless they have a True Type equivalent.

Starting with Windows 10, there is a new printer installed in the system called "Microsoft Print to PDF":

[image: Microsoft Print to PDF]

If you use that, instead of using the export to PDF feature, it actually works just fine. It properly embeds the fonts in vector format and is readable on devices that do not have the font installed.

Comment: Fyi. Exists also in Office 365

Comment: Crazy! The Print to PDF works. It's the only thing working.

Comment: Note. when printing, to avoid margins and white borders, I print (using PDF24 Creator) as follows. Settings: Printer Properties > Advanced... > Paper Size > PostScript Custom Page Size Definition. This will generate a *.prn file, which can be converted back to PDF by ps2pdf in command-line (use latest PowerShell).

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem when I used an Open type font to be able to use ligatures and old style numbers in word. With the true type format of the font I was not able to get those features.

This might not be a common problem for most people, but I found a strange work around in Word 2016 and Windows 7 that helped me to export ligatures in vector despite using the TTF. It could possibly become handy for some people.

I used the OTF version to apply the styles I wanted. I then changed all text to the TTF version of the font, and saved as PDF. All styles were preserved, and the file is in vector.

Comment: I spent almost 6 hours trying to solve this, but the only practical way to really solve the problem was to follow your suggestion to use TTF instead of OTF. I convert my fonts with sites like anyconv.com to TTF. Thank you for suggesting this solution.

Answer (score 1):

In Word 2007, from the "Save As PDF" dialog, you can click "Options", and then there is a checkbox for "Bitmap text when fonts may not be embedded" at the bottom of the next dialog box.  This suggests to me that some fonts may not be allowed to be embedded (for copyright reasons?).

Comment: Whatever I check or uncheck the "Bitmap text when fonts may not be embedded" I get a bitmap result. May it be possible to get vectorized font with an external software or an add-on? [I have to say that the font is directely vectorized when I use XeLaTeX but for some reason I have to use Word in this case]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with word and myriad (and other open-type fonts). If I uncheck the bitmap-option, I get an vectorized result but not with the correct font - that's no option for me.

My solution is to use an Adobe PDF printer (the original Adobe one is included in Acrobat Pro; v8.3 is free for download at the Adobe site; you have use an Internet *wayback machine* to find it). This works fine: correct font and vectorized result!

Comment: Quick note: 8.3 doesn't appear to work on Windows 10. Furthermore, printing to PDF as opposed to saving does not preserve inter-document links.