# Export PDF from Word with all fonts embedded

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, fonts

I have a Word document which has some texts in OpenType fonts. I want to distribute it in the PDF format that satisfies **all** the 3 requirements below:

- Embed uncommon OpenType fonts for global audience
- Searchable texts
- Structural document bookmarks (like a tree of headings)

I tried Export > PDF and PDF Options: **PDF/A complaint** and **Bitmap text when fonts may not be embedded** but they lost the document structure.
[image]
[image]
Can I make such a PDF file using Microsoft Word or is there any third-party software that allows me to do so?  Or, is there any way to add fonts into an existing PDF document?

I am using the latest Word (Office 365) on Windows 10.  I can script in Bash, PowerShell, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have installed Adobe Acrobat and have in Word an "Acrobat" ribbon pane,
then this might be possible.

I see that when clicking the *Preferences* button and then "Advanced settings...",
in the *Fonts* section an option called "Embed OpenType fonts" which is off
by default. Perhaps ticking the option and then OK, and using the Adobe
button of "Create PDF" will fix your problem:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You meant Adobe Acrobat DC Standard ($12.99/mo. - $155.88/yr.)? Are there less expensive solutions?

Comment: That is the version I'm using, but you could try and see if this works with the free [Adobe Acrobat Reader DC](https://get.adobe.com/reader/). Note also [this article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/get-the-adobe-acrobat-tab-to-appear-b83cbba3-7bc1-4c75-b8dc-511e07a283f0).

Comment: No, I couldn't find PDFMOfficeAddin.dll under C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC..

Comment: In Word menu *File > Options*, section *Save*, have you ticked "Embed fonts in the file"?

Comment: No, File > Options > Save > "Embed fonts in the file" only works when you save the document in Word format.

Comment: It's the last setting I can find. Afterward my only idea is to try an alternative product such as the free [LibreOffice]( https://www.libreoffice.org/) that can also save as pdf and with embedded fonts; maybe it can do better,

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there is no way to include OTF fonts with the vanilla "Export to PDF" function of Word.

A workaround that worked for me is to uninstall the OTF font and install the same font as TTF instead. I my case, I was fortunate that the font was offered in both formats...

Comment: This is correct, see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/652582/word-2013-export-to-pdf-how-to-keep-font-vectorized), and also [Microsofts official statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/office-suite-issues/fails-embedding-adobe-opentype-font), which mentions "Microsoft Office document" but apparently applies to "Save as PDF" as well. -- Note that _printing_ instead with "Microsoft Print to PDF" does embed the fonts.